Как программы создаются при помощи двоичного кода
Я уже довольно долгое время занимаюсь программированием, знаю, что мы в начале пишем код понятным нам языком, а затем он переводится в двоичный код (машинный). Так вот, мне стало интересно, а как вообще из двоичного кода могут создаваться какие программы, создаётся звук, картинка, любая игра. Также знаю, что есть ассамблеи, при помощи которого можно почти писать на машинном коде, но как мы сказали компьютеру, что какой-то определенный набор ноликов и единичек это какая-то функция?

Процессор идет по машинному коду, определенные последовательности байт для него означают определенные команды, он их выполняет. Рекомендую почитать книгу КОД Чарльза Петцольда. По поводу картинок - каждый цвет можно задать сочетанием 3 байт, каждый из них означает яркость красного, зеленого, синего, из этих цветом можно составить любые другие цвета, отображаемые экраном. А разные растровые форматы (PNG, JPEG, GIF и т.д.) служат для того, чтобы сжать эти "сырые" данные, ну GIF еще может хранить последовательность картинок для создания анимации.

Почитайте книжку https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B:%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B,%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B

какой-то определенный набор ноликов и единичек это какая-то функция - это задано расположением транзисторов в микросхеме (процессоре).

Мы сконструировали компьютер таким образом, что обнаружив в определенном месте некоторую последовательность нулей и единичек он выполняет соответствующую функцию (обычно ее называют машинной командой или instruction). Описание таких последовательностей для каждого семейства процессоров обычно описано в документе с названием ISA (instruction set architecture)

но как мы сказали компьютеру, что какой-то определенный набор ноликов и единичек это какая-то функция? никак, мы лишь вызвали команду функция в том слое абстракции в котором она определена, ниже функций нет. пример сетевой слоёнки - OSI в случае с цп\яп, в целом тоже слоёнка но уже "преобразований кода" и состав там другой: высокие яп > JVM/CLR/JIT > ASM > ISA > VHDL > PCB разумеется это лишь упрощенный список, в полном виде не находил. если кто составит - будет круто :3

Можно пойти от простого к сложному.
Представь большую панель с лампочками. Они могут гореть (1) или быть выключенными (0). Рядом поставим художника с холстом. Договоримся с ним что через эти лампочки (двоичный код) будем передавать цвет пикселя по порядку cлева направо.
К примеру, 0001|0010, где это 0001 - красный, 0010 - черный. Художник смотрит на сигналы на лампочке и рисует.
Теперь мы решили, что нам каждый раз тяжело писать какую лампочку зажигать и мы пишем язык программирования, где предаем:
красный|черный, а он все компилирует в 0001|0010
А ассемблер это просто более низкоуровневый язык программирования, где мы сами управляем в какую ячейку памяти что писать.
Для более подробного ответа, мне кажется, топика на форуме не хватит и надо углубляться в чтение книг.
